# Choose index of numpy matrix with regard to vector of probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, random

Given an n x n (stochastic) Numpy array A and  another Numpy array p in [0,1]^n. For each row `A_i` of `A`, I want to compute the smallest index `j*` such that `p_i <= A_i,j*`.

How can I implement this efficiently in Numpy? I guess this can somehow be done with `numpy.random.choice`.

Comment: What's the shape of `p`?

Comment: @Divikar (1,n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(p.T <= A).argmax(1)
```

In case, we don't find any element `p_i <= A_i,j*`, we can use an invalid specifier, say `-1`. For the same, we need a modified one -

```
mask = (p.T <= A)
out = np.where(mask.any(1), mask.argmax(1), -1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [140]: A
Out[140]: 
array([[5, 3, 8, 0, 1],
       [5, 4, 5, 2, 6],
       [2, 5, 5, 0, 4],
       [4, 2, 6, 5, 8],
       [4, 2, 5, 2, 6]])

In [141]: p
Out[141]: array([[8, 5, 8, 5, 6]])

In [142]: mask = (p.T <= A)

In [143]: np.where(mask.any(1), mask.argmax(1), -1)
Out[143]: array([ 2,  0, -1,  2,  4])
```

Comment: isn't `p` a probability array ranging from [0, 1] as OP mentioned?

Comment: @kmario23 I guess `A` would also be in the range then. I used int values for the sample as those are easier to visually verify.

Comment: I don't think transposing of `p` is needed. This is what we need `array([2, 4, 1, 3, 4])` as result which can be achieved without transposing

Comment: @kmario23 OP said `p` is `(1,n)` and we need that `(n)` axis as the rows because each element of `p` is to be compared against corresponding row of `A`. Thus, `8` is to be compared against first row of `A`, `5` against second row and so on. So, we need it that way. There are other ways to get the equivalent of `p.T` though like with `p.ravel()[:,None]`, etc.